# Find Matching Data Between a Column and a Referenced Data Set

Tags: sql, match

I need to compare two sets of data. The first data set is a single column from the database. The second data set is not in the database so I assume it will need to be referenced in a cache file.  The two sets do not have the same number of entries. The result needs to show only matching data. Any idea which direction I can go with this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the second set in the database? If so, then it would probably just be a basic `INNER JOIN ON columnName`

Comment: What do you mean "The second data set is not in the database"?

Comment: I have written a basic query to pull data from a single column for the current day. I need to make a query that a user can run everyday that will use that will compare this data to a temporary table I've created.